# when options are selected in quiz Alert bootstrap not working in React JS

Tags: reactjs

im trying to do an alert when the selected option in my quiz is right or wrong but it never alerts anything
this is my options part in the quiz

```
  {options.map((option, id) => (
            <Button
              size="lg"
              block
              key={id}
              className={`ui floating message options
            ${userAns === option ? "selected" : null}
           `}
              onClick={() => {
                this.checkAns(option);
                this.displayCorrectWrongAlerts();
              }}
            >
              {option}
              {this.state.userAns === this.state.answer ? (
                <FaCheck />
              ) : (
                <MdClose />
              )}
            </Button>
          ))}
```

Here is my function to produce the alerts

```
  displayCorrectWrongAlerts = answer => {
    if (this.state.userAns === answer) {
      return (
        <div>
          <Alert variant="danger">hellooo</Alert>
        </div>
      );
    }
  };
```

Any help with this

Comment: Please add codepen for the same so we can see the issue

Comment: @RajPurohit ok give me a minute

Comment: @RajPurohit https://codesandbox.io/s/hardcore-chaum-tq0c7 here is the codeboxe when u click the options you will be notified in the console if its correct or not

Comment: @RajPurohit any luck with above

Comment: Please check this codesandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/strange-babbage-8egww

Comment: let me know it's working or not?

Comment: yes its working thanks bro i got a better version of it working before u gave me the link thanks anyways

Comment: Okay Great bro..

Comment: can  u up vote my question if u dont mind?